# android application & facebook verification

Tags: android, facebook

i am developing an android application and i want to post some text to facebook, the problem is that when i attempt to create a facebook app. it asks me to verify my account either via mobile phone or credit card,

as i have no credit card i submitted my mobile phone number , they said that the confirmation code was sent to my phone , but actually i didn't recieve anything :S
i am from palestine , could that be the reason why i didn't recieve anything?"if my mobile supplier is not supported"

is there any other way by which i can post to fb from my app. without using the app. id or at least another way to get it?

Comment: Funny enough, but my last attempt to create a facebook account ended in the same trouble and I couldn't create an account neither. Yes, their policy is quite strict.

Comment: still i can't create one , luckily my team leader has one created long time ago , i am working on it now :))
thx alot stephane for ur support :))